# Control Timestamp precision of random timestamps

Tags: java, random, timestamp, simpledateformat, precision

I've a code for generating random date strings. However I came to find that when I generate a random timestamp, it contains some precision decimal points to seconds field. How ever my SimpleDateFormat does not contain such precision values, does anyone know what is wrong here, and how can I remove or control the precision values ?

**Code**

```
long rangeBegin = Timestamp.valueOf("2015-01-01 00:00:00").getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    String currentDateString = simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate);
    long rangeEnd = Timestamp.valueOf(currentDateString).getTime();
    long diff = rangeEnd - rangeBegin + 1;
    Timestamp randomTimestamp = new Timestamp(rangeBegin + (long)(Math.random() * diff));
```

**Sample output**

randomTimestamp = 2015-02-20 02:36:00.**646**

Thanks

**Edit** :

```
String randomTimestampString = String.valueOf(randomTimestamp).split("\\.")[0];
```

Comment: what is wrong with this?

Comment: See there is a decimal .646 at the end of the output, and I'm not expecting this

Answer (score 0):

The number after the decimal is for fractional precision, i.e. nanoseconds.
You could get rid of it by formatting or simply stripping them off using the String.substring() method.

Comment: thanks, but isn't my dateformat is sufficient to limit precision ?

Comment: I do not think so. From the looks of it, the date format will be valid only for currentDate.

Answer (score 0):

> randomTimestamp = 2015-02-20 02:36:00.**646**

According to the Timestamp [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) this 646 means the nanoseconds for precision

Comment: thanks for clarification. Anyway I can limit precision of timestamp ?